# Is it illegal to solicit a tip under false pretenses?

Tags: fraud

The question seems pretty obvious I suppose but I just remembered a thing that happened to me at a previous home and am just now realizing it may have been a scam or at least just as easily could have been.

The situation:
A few weeks before christmas my trash can had a note on it saying please don't attach christmas cards to the trash can as it's a robo can and to instead mail them to an address written on the note.

I don't remember the exact wording but suppose some con artist left these notes knowing that many people tip their trash collectors around christmas. Would that be fraud, or any other crime?  Even if they didn't claim to be the garbage collector?

Comment: It isn't fraud to request a Christmas card, but the wording matters.